# Updating Laravel from 5.3 to 5.4 issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm upgrading Laravel from version **5.3 to 5.4**.
When updating composer I'm getting the following error:

> Update failed (D:\app\vendor/laravel/framework/src\Illuminate\Events does not exist and could not be created.)

I'm running Windows cmd with administrator permissions.

Before upgrading I was upgrading from 5.2 to 5.3 and evertything went very well.

Comment: What happens if you create the folder manually and then run update?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In the end I manually deleted the vendor/laravel/framework folder (and its contents) then ran `composer update`. That fixed it for me. Make sure everything is backed up / versioned controlled first though #obvs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already upgraded my app manually.